# How can i send a VCard to Samsung and Nokia phones using SMS?

Tags: sms, nokia, vcf-vcard

I don't know what is wrong with my syntax (or Nokia & Samsung phones) because when i send it to Sony Ericsson it will be processed and save as a Contact but when i send it to Nokia or Samsung it will be displayed as plain message.

This is my syntax & works perfectly in Sony Ericsson:

```
   BEGIN:VCARD
   VERSION:2.1
   N:myname;
   TEL;VOICE;WORK:0999999999
   TEL;CELL;WORK:0999999999
   EMAIL:myemail@example.com
   END:VCARD
```

Comment: Nokia phones can receive VCARDs in SMS messages, as you can see by sending a contact from the address book.  I don't know how the VCARD is delimited in the message or how you'd generate an appropriate message programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more success if you send the vCard to the WAP vCard SMS port, 0x23f4, as a binary SMS. It is entirely possible the Nokia handsets are expecting vCards to come from this port.

Comment: Is there anyway to set this port in UDH ? I'm just sending this SMS through a gateway and i can''t access or install any app on the phone.

Comment: Yes, the port is set in the UDH. Plenty of examples of how to do this on the 'net. For example, http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/binary-sms-sending-rich-content-devices-using-sms

Answer (score 1):

Few of the cellphones can't detect vCards in SMSs and read it as plain message and this could also be due to version incompatibility issue. As you have posted this question here you want to do all the things programmatically so for **j2me** if your handset emulator version is having specs as jsr 75 and your emulator is able to access bluetooth or network interface(depend on manufacturer specs) you can read/write vCard records into your handsets via network(gprs/edge) or bluetooth.